# Azaan from multiple mosques in the same vicinity

Tags: masjid, adhan

I live in a Muslim-dominated locality. Some of my friends who are Hindu also live in the same area.
There are close to 4 to 5 mosques in the vicinity not too far from each other and they call for prayer at the same time (plus minus a few minutes).
My friend asked me a question if Azaan from the mosque is a call for prayer to the people, then won't a call from a single mosque will do the job? Why does every mosque in the same local vicinity need to make the call for the prayer?

Comment: Let's put it this way: Adhan itself is a sunnah for every Muslim, but some scholars elevate it to a fard kifaya. So that calling for the prayer from a mosque is not only a rewarded good deed, but could also be an obligation.

Comment: @Medi1Saif : Is there any such ruling in the Quran or Hadith on the basis of which the scholars have elevated it to a fard kifaya. Also, I agree that "Adhan itself is a sunnah for every Muslim" but here I am asking about the Adhaan from the mosque and not about the individual.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If there are more than one mosque in the same vicinity, calling azan from only one mosque is not an option as prayer will be conducted in each mosque, so the call has to be from all mosque.  When azan is called at same time from multiple mosque, it can be very much annoying to people there. So one solution to this is to use loud speaker in only one mosque and rest of the mosque they can call Azan without loud speaker.

Comment: But as the mosques are in the same vicinity, one call would do the job right?

Comment: we should not compromise on the sunnah, if prayer is conducted in all masjid, then azaan should be also in all